# Cant convert JSON to array in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, http

Hi everyone I have some problems with angular, I made a request in $http so i have a JSON like:

{"y":"1","a":"0"}

and I want to convert it to an array like

{y:1, a:0}

I'd already tried whit angular.fromJson(myData) but it doesnt works 
Hope you´ll help me because Im a begginer

Comment: BTW that is an **object** not **Array**.

Comment: what is the purpose? what do you want to do? explain clearer ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a hint/suggestion, something you might overlooked. It is hard to understand your question, clarify if this is not what you are looking for.

Maybe for some reason you got `"{"y":"1","a":"0"}"` back, which is a string.
If you need to get a JSON object from it then use `JSON.parse(string)` function.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method is used to convert json string response to an array, object, number

```
    var temp = [];
    temp = angular.fromJson(json); 
    console.log(temp);
```

This function will convert and return

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the object that you have after parsing the JSON and the object that you want is that the string values need to be number values.

Loop though the keys and convert the values:

```
for (key in obj) obj[key] = parseInt(obj[key], 10);
```